# Parsing an excel with more than 12000 lines in PHP with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, bigdata

I have a trouble when I try to upload and parse through PHPExcel library a xlsx file with 12500 rows and 20 columns The whole process takes about ten minutes to end, it does querys and validations. The upload works fine, but when it starts to parse the excel file with all that rows the excel library fails.
I have to divided into two files the big file, so it works fine.

Is posible parse a file of more than 12000 lines and 20 columns in PHPExcel, 
without it will fail?

**And I'd like your suggestion**.

Is more fast and light parse a csv file(I think so) than parse a excel file, when we are talking as many lines?

The browsers die about minute three of the execution, but the process in server continues.
Is there anyway that the browser doesn't reset the connection? and Why the process continues in server and the browser dies?

I'm thinking to pass the process to ajax for avoid this point, What do you think of that?

What's the better way to parse this type of files with that number of lines?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's perfectly possible, but it really depends how you've coded your script, what memory management (caching) you might be using, what additional processing you're doing, etc. If you're working with large files though, we always recommend running the processing as a background task. Upload the file via the browser, reporting back to the browser that the file is now awaiting processing; then use a cron task to handle that processing in the background.

Comment: Parsing a CSV file will __always__ be faster than using PHPExcel to process an Excel file, because you're working with plain text rathe rthan a complex binary format, and a CSV can simply be processed line by line; and you can use built-in PHP functions like fgetcsv() directly.

Comment: An Ajax request is still a standard http request made by the browser; it's still likely to timeout in exactly the same way as your current solution

Comment: I like the subject of running it as a background task that's a great idea that I don't think

Comment: I didn't think. Thank you very much!